# General question on where to learn modulation and radio theory

Tags: modulation

Does anyone have any good books/videos or courses to learn about radio waves,frequencys,phase spread spectrum and modulation?
I need a something that goes through the basics until advanced.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

John G. Proakis, Fundamentals of Communication Systems. Second edition, Pearson 2014.

Simon Haykin. 2009. Communication Systems (5th. ed.). Wiley Publishing.

The 2022 ARRL Handbook for Radio Communications, The National Association for Amateur Radio

You can learn the prerequisite knowledge from the following:

Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky, and S. Hamid Nawab. 1996. Signals & systems (2nd ed.). Prentice-Hall, Inc., USA.

Comment: If you're buying used, pretty much any ARRL handbook from 2000 on up -- from 1945 on up if you can skip the spread-spectrum bits.  For that matter, Oppenheim & Willsky, and Proakis, have been updating their books since I was in school 40 years ago; anything in the last 10 years will be complete, and anything in the last 40 will have everything except spread spectrum.